# Extend Array without using class keyword

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to extend buildins without using the class keyword?
As I understand, the class keyword is a bit more than just syntactic sugar. But will this or something like this work?

```
MyArray = function () {}
MyArray.prototype = Object.create(Array.prototype)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Of course*. Inheritance in javascript was a thing before the `class` keyword existed, as you note. Your example comes pretty close to how you would do this. Indeed, [the documentation for `Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create#Classical_inheritance_with_Object.create()) gives an example of how to achieve inheritance without ever using `class`.

To apply their example to yours, you might do it like so:

```js
const MyArray = function() {
  Array.call(this); // Call parent constructor
}

MyArray.prototype = Object.create(Array.prototype);
MyArray.prototype.constructor = MyArray; // Set constructor

// Add methods:
MyArray.prototype.test = function() {
  this.forEach(element => console.log("Element:", element));
}

// Now you can create new MyArray's that inherit from Array:

const myArray = new MyArray();

myArray.push("hello");
myArray.push("world");
myArray.test();
```

Comment: Thats great! Why Babel cannot do that?

Comment: at least the Browser seems to make a difference with your version vs the class version. `Array.isArray(myArray)` returns `false`. So its not the exact equivalent to the class based inheritance, right?